# Mongoid - having a lot of timeouts

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rubygems, mongoid, rack

I have a lot of errors of timeout in Mongoid. The error says that it's taking place in `connectable.rb#16`. I found the source of this https://github.com/mongoid/moped/blob/master/lib/moped/sockets/connectable.rb#L16

or here as well

https://github.com/mongoid/moped/blob/master/lib/moped/sockets/connectable.rb#L45
https://github.com/mongoid/moped/blob/master/lib/moped/sockets/connectable.rb#L60

So what do I have to do with that error, how do I raise the timeout to get rid of the error?

**P.S.** It's a sinatra app, here is the stack trace of one of them.

```
Timeout::Error at /
execution expired
file: connectable.rb location: write line: 60



/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/sockets/connectable.rb 60 in write
        handle_socket_errors { super }
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/sockets/connectable.rb 60 in block in write
        handle_socket_errors { super }
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/sockets/connectable.rb 78 in handle_socket_errors
        yield
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/sockets/connectable.rb 60 in write
        handle_socket_errors { super }
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/connection.rb 156 in block in write
        socket.write(buf)
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/connection.rb 202 in with_connection
        yield @sock
```

Comment: can u share the stack trace?

Comment: could you provide a `writeconcern` for you connection?